# RxJava - Opposite of switchMap() Operator?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I am wondering if there is a way to compose existing operators to perform the opposite of a `switchMap()`.

The `switchMap()` will chase after the latest emission it receives and cancel any `Observable` it previously was executing. Let's say I flipped it, and I want to ignore all emissions coming to a `xxxMap()` operator while it is busy with the first emission it received. It will keep ignoring emissions until it finishes emitting the current `Observable` inside of it. Then it will process the next emission it receives.

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Source Emitted Value: " + i))
        .ignoreWhileBusyMap(i -> doIntensiveProcess(i).subcribeOn(Schedulers.computation())) 
        .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Subscriber received Value: " + i));
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? In the above example, if `intensiveProcess()` were to last three seconds, the `ignoreWhileBusyMap()` would process `0` but likely ignore emissions `1` and `2` coming from `interval()`.It would then process `3` but likely ignore `4` and `5`, and so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, gate the processing of a value by a boolean that is set after the processing finished:

```
AtomicBoolean gate = new AtomicBoolean(true);

Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.flatMap(v -> {
    if (gate.get()) {
        gate.set(false);

        return Observable.just(v).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .doAfterTerminate(() -> gate.set(true));
    } else {
        return Observable.empty();
    }
})
.take(10)
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

**Edit**

Alternative:

```
Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.onBackpressureDrop()
.flatMap(v -> {
    return Observable.just(v).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}, 1)
.take(10)
.toBlocking()
.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

You can change `onBackpressureDrop` to `onBackpressureLatest` to continue immediately with the latest value.

Comment: Awesome, I did something similar with a `Semaphore` but was hoping to use a purely reactive composition with existing operators. I suppose I could wrap all this up in a `Transformer` though.

Comment: Use a deferred transformer to avoid sharing the gate across multiple end-subscribers.

Comment: Just realized your solution is not block-y like mine though, so I'll switch to this. Thanks!

Comment: Haha yes, I'll keep that in mind this time : ) Won't make that mistake again

Comment: thanks for your alternative. I was able to compose it into an extension function for Kotlin: `inline fun <T,R> Observable<T>.ignoreWhileBusyMap(crossinline mapper: (T) -> Observable<R>) = onBackpressureDrop()
    .flatMap({ mapper.invoke(it)} ,1)`

Answer (score 5):

I know that this an old thread but currently there is a RxJs operator that does just that.

The operator is `exhaustMap`.

According to the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap):

> ExhaustMap projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable only if the previous projected Observable has completed.

Docs [example](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap#example):

```
import { fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = clicks.pipe(
  exhaustMap(ev => interval(1000).pipe(take(5)))
);
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: This is currently the best answer as ExhaustMap did not exist when the original answer was accepted.

Comment: ExhaustMap still doesn't exist in RxJava, which is what was originally asked. I'm so disappointed RxJava doesn't have it though, coming from RxJs.

Answer (score 0):

To answer Jeopardy style: what is `concatMap`?

`concatMap` will subscribe to the first `Observable` and will not subscribe to subsequent `Observable`s until the previous `Observable` calls `onComplete()`.

In this respect it is the "opposite" of `switchMap` which eagerly unsubscribes from previous `Observable`s when a new one comes along.

`concatMap` wants to hear everything that each Observable has to say, whereas `switchMap` is a social butterfly, and moves on as soon as another Observable is available.

Comment: Not quite, if you read the question closely you'll see I'm pursuing a behavior that has little to do with `concatMap` or its perceived opposite. To follow your analogy, I was looking for a `xxxMap` operator that would focus on talking to the first Observable it encounters and tell any subsequent Observables "not now, I'm busy talking to this guy". Only when his conversation is done he will allow another Observable to engage with him.

Comment: That's what `concatMap` does.

Comment: I believe `concatMap()` is the same as `flatMap()` but it doesn't interleave. It guarantees all emissions will ultimately be emitted even if it queues them. But the operator I was asking for simply ignores subsequent emissions while it is busy.

Comment: Ah, ok, by "ignore emissions" I thought you meant "ignore emissions for now", but as is spelled out in the last paragraph of your question: these should emissions be dropped. In that case, I like the solution akarnokd posed.